# Replicate the tuple values to create random dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns which are `source and destination` in a csv. I have a total of 67 tuple values as of now which I want to randomly generate for 1000000 rows. I want to create a dataframe for 1000000 rows which have these 67 tuple values. Any method I can do the same in python.

Thanks

Edit :

Sample Data is pretty straight forward -

```
source  destination
a         b
a         c
a         d
a         e
b         a
b         c
b         d
b         e
c         a
c         b
```

Comment: Can you create sample data?

Comment: Do you have a tuple with 67 elements and want to generate a dataframe with 2 columns and a million rows containing only values from your tuple and randomly distributed?

Comment: Use `df = df.sample(1000000)`

Comment: @SpghttCd yes, there would be repeated tuple values for sure...

Comment: @jezrael I tried `df = pd.read_csv('tuple.csv'); df = df.sample(100000, replace=True)` it returns my df as 'Nan'